# Regex Matching everything between 2 repeating values

Tags: javascript, regex, icalendar

I am making a reminder application and I want to be able to support iCalender importing. This is why I want to be able to extract events. This is the basic format of an event in iCalender:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
......
......
END:VEVENT
```

All of these events are in one file so I will have a big list like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
......
......
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
......
......
END:VEVENT
```

These events will have a start date and an end date

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
......
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160403
......
END:VEVENT
```

When trying to extract just the event, it is not always the same format. The start date and end date can be before or after other certain fields.

Currently I have:

```
/BEGIN:VEVENT[\s\S]*?DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402[\s\S]*?END:VEVENT/
```

However this doesn't match just the event itself, it matches from the first match of `BEGIN:VEVENT`, matches everything until the date, and then finishes the match at the following `END:VEVENT`.

So in some of the events further down the list trying to match them includes lots of others. Is there a way I can match the `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:` and only the previous nearest `BEGIN:VEVENT` and the following `END:VEVENT` just to extract the single event for that day?

Comment: Ok, here it is - https://regex101.com/r/oE6bB5/2

Comment: No I wasn't able to figure it out, I'm very inexperienced at regex, wow thanks very much thats brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a tempered greedy token that can be used to obtain the smallest window possible between two substrings in a text. Since your text is multiline, you cannot use `.` atom to match any characters, you need to use either `[^]` or `[\s\S]`.

So, use

```
/BEGIN:VEVENT((?:(?!\b(?:END|BEGIN):VEVENT\b)[\s\S])*DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402[\s\S]*?)END:VEVENT/g
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE6bB5/2)

The `(?:(?!\b(?:END|BEGIN):VEVENT\b)[\s\S])*` part matches any text that is not `BEGIN:VEVENT` and `END:VEVENT` (as whole words due to the `\b` word boundary).

```js
var re = /BEGIN:VEVENT((?:(?!\b(?:END|BEGIN):VEVENT\b)[\s\S])*DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402[\s\S]*?)END:VEVENT/g; 
var str = 'BEGIN:VEVENT\n......\n......\nEND:VEVENT\nBEGIN:VEVENT\n......\n......\nEND:VEVENT\nThese events will have a start date and an end date\n\nBEGIN:VEVENT\n......\nDTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402\nDTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160403\n......\nEND:VEVENT';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[0]);
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res.map(x => x.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br/>")), 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Note that `[\s\S]*?` can also be replaced with the above tempered greedy token, but it seems that it is not necessary since the VEVENT blocks are well-formed and there are no nested VEVENT blocks. If there are nested VEVENT blocks, the `[\s\S]*?` should be replaced with the tempered greedy token.

Comment: Great thanks for explaining it, that is a very clever way of doing it. So if I understand the (?!\b(?:END|BEGIN):VEVENT\b) is basically saying if my BEGIN:VEVENT is followed by either END:VEVENT or BEGIN:VEVENT without a DTSTART between them stop capturing?

Comment: That token matches any text that is not `BEGIN:VEVENT` and `END:VEVENT` up to the first `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402`. Thus, if the `DTSTART` is in another VEVENT block, the appropriate `BEGIN:VEVENT` will be matched. You can add some more options to the alternation in the negative lookahead part of the token to also not match `DTSTART`, like `(?!\b(?:END|BEGIN):VEVENT\b|DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160402)` - not sure it will work faster.